# How to fix “Could not update; currently locked” caused by using DAO.Recordset2.Edit while a form is being edited

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

DAO.Recordset2.Edit is causing a “Could not update; currently locked” error.

I want to save the edited form, update the record and refresh the form.

But all attempts to save the form fail to fix the error. They fail to clear the record lock. Closing the form clears the lock, but that is messy, looking for a better way.

Steps:

- typed data into a form.
- Clicked a button that triggers:

  ```
  ' saves the form but does not clear the record lock
  If Me.Dirty Then
      Me.Dirty = False
  End If
  ```
- click another button that triggers adding a photo:

  ```
  Private Sub EndPhotoTaking_Click()
    Dim attachmentField As DAO.Field2
    Dim photoItemRecordSet As DAO.Recordset2
    With [Forms]![Inspection - All sub sections].Form
        Set photoItemRecordSet = .Recordset
    End With
    Set attachmentField = photoItemRecordSet("Photo")
    Set photoItemAttachment = attachmentField.Value
    '---- error “Could not update; currently locked” on line below 
    photoItemRecordSet.Edit
  ```

Then I get the error “Could not update; currently locked”.

I am using VBA to add a picture into the record, but it is not working. It does not work if the record has been changed in any way.

It is running the Line of code "Me.Dirty = False", so this saves the record. But then I get the error. I only get the error if I enter data into the from.

The form that I enter data into contains a subform, would that have an impact? I suspect it does because I have another form that does not have a subform and it works just fine with the same code. Is there anything that would cause "Me.Dirty = False" to fail to clear the lock.

I have also tried "DoCmd.Save acForm, formName", but that did not help.

The table is sharepoint list style.

*Edit*

- Added extra code to show origin of photoItemRecordSet.Edit
- updated title and description. Added details to say saving the form is not clearing the record lock.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `Me.Dirty = False` to `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`? I never got it work to change the Dirty-Attribute by myself in code. There was always an error. But it should work according to the web. BTW `DoCmd.Save acForm, formName` should save the form design, not the recordset.

Comment: @asdev yes. For some reason saving the record is not releasing the lock.

Comment: Maybe the lock is configured in database options or in the form properties.

Comment: Form -> Record Lock = No Locks  ... Yes, re-creating the form from scratch looks like the next thing to try.

Comment: I meant:  _I have also tried "DoCmd.Save acForm, formName", but that did not help._ This command is NOT meant for saving a recordset, but the form-object itself (it will probably save the recordset anyway in the background by Access itself). 

It would be helpful if you would give the whole (abstracted with dummy variables) code of the sub

Comment: What is `ItemRecordSet`?

Comment: @asdev thanks. The form "Record Source" is a table and I can confirm  DoCmd.Save acForm saves the record, but for some strange reason it is not dropping the lock. Locking looks complex, there looks to be many options for changing how locking is done. So far I have just used default options for record locks.

Comment: @Gustav thanks. photoItemRecordSet is the DAO.Recordset2 of a master form, a master form that contains 3 subforms.

Comment: Does one of your subforms hold a reference to the parent-table?
Another workaround: Instead of using a reference to the recordset and with edit command: Just do your operations on the form controls.

Comment: @asdev >do your operbutations on the form controls .... I looked at doing that, but I could not see any way to do it with attachment style fields.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: close the form. Update the record. Reopen the form.

This works but is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RecordsetClone`:

```
Set photoItemRecordSet = .RecordsetClone
photoItemRecordSet.Bookmark = .Bookmark
```

Comment: Does not work. ..... Does not clear the lock...... I also tried creating the record set using CurrentDb.OpenRecordset and that did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, the record was saved and a requery didn't help. I was finally able to set the form RecordSource to the recordsource that I originally had it set to again, navigate to the record I was on and then the add photo worked.
I put this code in the Error Handler;

```html
If Err.Number = 3218 Then
    rstEmployee.Close
    Set rstEmployee = Nothing
    Me.RecordSource = "qryPersonnelData"
    Set rstEmployee = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "[ID] = " & thisID
    Resume
```

I hope this helps someone.